# Graphics DrawString Not Showing Up in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to make a Java program that allows you to program simple games using drag-and-drop code panels. Using a JTextField in my code panel created a glitch where there would be a long delay before the size updated, so I resorted to making my own JTextField using a JPanel.

Here is the code:

```
package editor;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class JCustomTextField extends JPanel {

    String text;
    int xMargin;
    int yMargin;
    int width;
    int height;

    public JCustomTextField(String initText, int xMargin, int yMargin, int height, int width) {

        this.xMargin = xMargin;
        this.yMargin = yMargin;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.text = initText;

        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 2));
        setBounds(0, 0, width, height);


        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                text.concat("" + arg0.getKeyChar());
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(text, xMargin, yMargin);
    }
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

}
```

Now I create a JComponent array containing a JLabel and the text panel and add it to the code panel.

```
JComponent[] jumpComps = {new JLabel("Jump Height:"), new JCustomTextField("10", 2, 2, 20, 50)};
    CodePanel jumpPanel = new CodePanel(0,0, jumpComps, 1);
```

The border shows up, but not the text.

Here's a picture of the code panel:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwU0v.png]

I am using the Substance Graphite Glass Look and Feel.

Comment: (1-) Don't create a custom component. Fix your layout problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [KeyEvent documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html):

> The getKeyChar method always returns a valid Unicode character or CHAR_UNDEFINED. Character input is reported by KEY_TYPED events: KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events are not necessarily associated with character input. Therefore, the result of the getKeyChar method is guaranteed to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED events.
>
> For key pressed and key released events, the getKeyCode method returns the event's keyCode. For key typed events, the getKeyCode method always returns `VK_UNDEFINED`.

`getKeyChar` is valid only for keyTyped events.  Its return value is undefined for keyPressed and keyReleased events.

All that said, a text field is much more complex than this.  You aren’t handling cursor rendering, backspacing, arrow keys, selection, or accessibility.  You’re better off using a real JTextField and properly addressing your layout problem.

Comment: @Aterix That's a different question from what you've asked. You'd be better off deleting this question and ask a new one, which demonstrates your drag and drop solution and the problem with the layout